# Get file list from owncloud

Tags: c#, asp.net, webdav, owncloud

I want to get file list from owncloud on my ASP site. I was succeed using 
`curl -X PROPFIND -u user:password "http://yourserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/"` from linux but I can't get the same result using default http request with propfind type in order to use it then in c# `https://user:password@host/owncloud/remote.php/webdav`. I get 400 code as a result on my request. Also I tried webdavclient from nuget but received method not allowed exception.

```
        IClient c = new Client(new NetworkCredential { UserName = "user", Password = "password" });
        var client = new WebDAVClient.Client(new NetworkCredential());
        c.Server = "xxx.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/";
        var isfolderCreated = c.CreateDir("/", "lalala").Result;
```

Could anybody say to me how to send http request to owncloud to get the file list? I tried webdav protocol that is used by clients but maybe I should try anything else?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share your [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills , clarified a bit but that's all I have

Comment: It **can't** be all you have. You clearly have written some code. `Also I tried webdavclient from nuget but received method not allowed exception.` says as much. Show us that code.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue that prevented me. I just didn't use basic authorization correctly in http request. Since I add correct credentials I could send the http request and get the response. And here is the code I use in c#:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("xxx.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/");

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
                request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                request.Method = @"PROPFIND";
                request.Headers.Add(@"Translate", "F");

                var httpGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


                using (var responseStream = httpGetResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    long responseLength = httpGetResponse.ContentLength;

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        var files = XElement.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

                        streamReader.Close();
                    }

                    responseStream.Close();
                }
```